# weak derivative equals 0 implies constant

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, weak-derivatives

Let $W^{1,p}(U)$ be the Sobolev space. Suppose that U is connected bounded domain in Rn and $u∈W^{1,p}(U)$ satisfies $Du=0$ a.e. in U. Prove that u is constant a.e. in U.

I have worked out the method which use $u_ε=u∗ρ_ε, Du_ε=0$ and convergence.

Could you help me to come up with another way to prove it?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "the method which use $u_ε=u∗ρ_ε, Du_ε=0$ and convergence"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement that $u$ has weak derivative zero is equivalent to the statement that for all smooth functions $\varphi:U \to \Bbb R$, we have
$$
\int_U u\,\nabla \varphi = 0.
$$
Now, it suffices to note that for any characteristic function $\Bbb 1_S$ associated with a closed $S \subset U$, a (bounded) sequence $\varphi_k$ can be selected such that the first component of $\nabla \varphi_k$ approaches $\Bbb 1_S$.